# How to not focus any element after opening a NgbModal?

Tags: angular

I have the following ngForm inside a template which i pass as an argument for opening a NgbModal:

```
<form #optionsForm="ngForm" noValidate (ngSubmit)="saveOptions()" id="optionsForm">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="customFile">Icon</label>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Select icon</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    // more will come
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary pieChart" aria-hidden="true" [disabled]="!optionsForm.valid">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Whenever i open the NgbModal, the focus is set on the first input element which looks like this:

[image]

I do not want any element to be focused after i open the form, pressing tab then should focus the first element. Is there any way to start at `tabIndex=-1` whenever the form is opened or so?

Comment: Try using HTML autofocus attribute. Or get the element reference in the TypeScript and call focus method

Answer (score 1):

Can perhaps be seen as a hack (?), but seems to work fine...

There is [`ngbAutofocus`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#focus) which overrides the behavior of focusing on first element. Adding that for example to the form tag seems to solve the issue:

```
<form .... ngbAutofocus>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvffsp?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)**